# What's the difference between InterlockedCompareExchange Release() and Acquire()?

Tags: winapi, synchronization, interlocked

What's the difference between `InterlockedCompareExchangeRelease()` and `InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire()`?

When I try to learn the synchronization functions with WIN32 API, I find there are two functions named differently but seems to do the same thing:

```
LONG __cdecl InterlockedCompareExchangeRelease(
  __inout  LONG volatile *Destination,
  __in     LONG Exchange,
  __in     LONG Comparand
);
```

and

```
LONG __cdecl InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire(
  __inout  LONG volatile *Destination,
  __in     LONG Exchange,
  __in     LONG Comparand
);
```

I check the MSDN, it says those functions are:

> Performs an atomic compare-and-exchange operation on the specified
>   values. The function compares two specified 32-bit values and
>   exchanges with another 32-bit value based on the outcome of the
>   comparison.

but for `InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire()`,

> The operation is performed with acquire memory access semantics.

and for `InterlockedCompareExchangeRelease()`,

> The exchange is performed with release memory access semantics.

So I'm curious about the difference between these two functions.
When to use the **acquire memory access semantics** or **release memory access semantics**?
Are there any examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plain version uses a full barrier while the suffixed versions only deals with loads **or** stores, this can be faster on some CPUs (Itanium-based processors etc)

MSDN has a article about [Acquire and Release Semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540496.aspx) and the [Interlocked* API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as [this great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/03/8969397.aspx). The [Linux memory barrier documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) might also be useful...

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> Acquire memory semantics specify that the memory operation being performed by the current thread will be visible before any other memory operations are attempted. Release memory semantics specify that the memory operation being performed by the current thread will be visible after all other memory operations have been completed. These semantics allow you to force memory operations to be performed in a specific order. Use acquire semantics when entering a protected region and release semantics when leaving it.