# How to understand acquire and release semantics?

Tags: windows

I found out three function from MSDN , below:

```
1.InterlockedDecrement().

2.InterlockedDecrementAcquire().

3.InterlockedDecrementRelease().
```

I knew those fucntion use to decrement a value as an atomic operation, but i don't know distinction between the three function

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between InterlockedCompareExchange Release() and Acquire()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764181/whats-the-difference-between-interlockedcompareexchange-release-and-acquire)

Comment: Note that on x86 processors, there is no difference.  Of the architectures that run Windows, release and acquire are separately available on Itanium, not on x86 and x64, and I'm not sure about ARM.

Comment: This blog post is excellent https://davekilian.com/acquire-release.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> (um... but don't ask me what does it mean exactly)

I'll take a stab at that.

Something to remember is that the compiler, or the CPU itself, may reorder memory reads and writes if they appear to not deal with each other.

This is useful, for instance, if you have some code that, maybe is updating a structure:

```
if ( playerMoved ) {
  playerPos.X += dx;
  playerPos.Y += dy; 

  // Keep the player above the world's surface.
  if ( playerPos.Z + dz > 0 ) {
     playerPos.Z += dz;
  }
  else {
     playerPos.Z = 0;
  }
}
```

Most of above statements may be reordered because there's no data dependency between them, in fact, a superscalar CPU may execute most of those statements simultaneously, or maybe would start working on the Z section sooner, since it doesn't affect X or Y, but might take longer.

Here's the problem with that - lets say that you're attempting lock-free programming. You want to perform a whole bunch of memory writes to, maybe, fill in a shared queue. You signal that you're done by finally writing to a flag.

Well, since that flag appears to have nothing to do with the rest of the work being done, the compiler and the CPU may reorder those instructions, and now you may set your 'done' flag before you've actually committed the rest of the structure to memory, and now your "lock-free" queue doesn't work.

This is where Acquire and Release ordering semantics come into play. I set that I'm doing work by setting a flag or so with an Acquire semantic, and the CPU guarantees that any memory games I play after that instruction stay actually below that instruction. I set that I'm done by setting a flag or so with a Release semantic, and the CPU guarantees that any memory games I had done just before the release actually stay before the release.

Normally, one would do this using explicit locks - mutexes, semaphores, etc, in which the CPU already knows it has to pay attention to memory ordering. The point of attempting to create 'lock free' data structures is to provide data structures that are thread safe (for some meaning of thread safe), that don't use explicit locks (because they are very slow).

Creating lock-free data structures is possible on a CPU or compiler that doesn't support acquire/release ordering semantics, but it usually means that some slower memory ordering semantic is used. For instance, you could issue a full memory barrier - everything that came before this instruction has to actually be committed before this instruction, and everything that came after this instruction has to be committed actually after this instruction. But that might mean that I wait for a bunch of actually irrelevant memory writes from earlier in the instruction stream (perhaps function call prologue) that has nothing to do with the memory safety I'm trying to implement.

Acquire says "only worry about stuff after me". Release says "only worry about stuff before me". Combining those both is a full memory barrier.

Answer (score 2):

http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

> Acquire semantics is a property which can only apply to operations
>   which read from shared memory, whether they are read-modify-write
>   operations or plain loads. The operation is then considered a
>   read-acquire. Acquire semantics prevent memory reordering of the
>   read-acquire with any read or write operation which follows it in
>   program order.
>
> Release semantics is a property which can only apply to operations
>   which write to shared memory, whether they are read-modify-write
>   operations or plain stores. The operation is then considered a
>   write-release. Release semantics prevent memory reordering of the
>   write-release with any read or write operation which precedes it in
>   program order.

(um... but don't ask me what does it mean *exactly*)

Comment: At a guess, it is mutex behaviour? As though a mutex guarding access to the memory is acquired/released?

Comment: @user268396: It's in some ways similar. [This](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) and [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) video explain it all to you more than you wanted to know about it.

Comment: @MK - I attempted to extend your answer, but this is a subject I know only enough about to be dangerous. If you would, would you review my answer and see if that makes sense to you?