# Difference between Interlocked, InterlockedAcquire, and InterlockedRelease if single thread reordering is impossible

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, visual-studio-2017

In all likelihood, a lockless implementation is already overkill for the purposes of my application, but I wanted to look into memory barriers and lockless-ness anyways in case I ever actually need to use these concepts in the future.

From what I can tell:

1. an "InterlockedAcquire" function performs an atomic operation while preventing the compiler from moving code statements after the InterlockedAcquire to before the InterlockedAcquire.
2. an "InterlockedRelease" function performs an atomic operation while preventing the compiler from moving code statements before the InterlockedRelease to after the InterlockedRelease.
3. a vanilla "Interlocked" function performs an atomic operation while preventing the compiler from moving code statements in either direction across the Interlocked call.

My question is, if a function is structured such that the compiler can't reorder any of the code anyways because doing so would affect single-threaded behavior, is there a difference between any of the variants of an Interlocked function, or all they all effectively the same? Is the only difference between them how they interact with code reordering?

For a more concrete example, here's my current application - the produce() function as part of what will eventually be a multiple producer, single consumer queue built using a circular buffer:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue {
    private:
        long headIndex;
        long tailIndex;
        T* array[MAXQUEUESIZE];
    public:
        Queue() {
            headIndex = 0;
            tailIndex = 0;
            memset(array, 0, MAXQUEUESIZE*sizeof(void*);
        }
        ~Queue() {
        }

        bool produce(T value) {
            //1) prevents concurrent calls to produce() from causing corruption:
            long indexRetVal;
            long reservedIndex;
            do {
                reservedIndex = tailIndex;
                indexRetVal = InterlockedCompareExchange64(&tailIndex, (reservedIndex + 1) % MAXQUEUESIZE, reservedIndex);
            } while (indexRetVal != reservedIndex);

            //2) allocates the node.
            T* newValPtr = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T));
            if (newValPtr == null) {
                OutputDebugString("Queue: malloc returned null");
                return false;
            }
            *newValPtr = value;

            //3) prevents a concurrent call to consume from causing corruption by atomically replacing the old pointer:
            T* valPtrRetVal = InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(array + reservedIndex, newValPtr, null);
            //if the previous value wasn't null, then our circular buffer overflowed:
            if (valPtrRetVal != null) {
                OutputDebugString("Queue: circular buffer overflowed");
                free(newValPtr); //as pointed out by RbMm
                return false;
            }

            //otherwise, everything worked fine
            return true;
        }
};
```

As I understand it, 3) will occur after 1) and 2) regardless of what I do anyways, but I should change 1) to an InterlockedRelease because I don't care whether it occurs before or after 2) and I should let the compiler decide.

Comment: you use `InterlockedCompareExchange64` on 32 bit `long tailIndex` and compiler nothing say here ? if malloc fail - `reservedIndex` will be leaked ? if on step 3 circular buffer overflowed - not need free `newValPtr` before return ? in *1* you not need any fence at all. at *3* store `newValPtr` with release fence

Comment: Could you explain why newValPtr need to be stored with a release fence?

Comment: for all data stored in location to which point `newValPtr` will be guarantee visible by thread which read `newValPtr`  - read must be with acquire semantic and store with release.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it so I'll try a different question:
Do acquire and release semantics affect behavior in anyway besides preventing certain forms of code reordering by the compiler?

Comment: here any code will be not reordered by compiler anyway. even if you will be not use interlocked, fence , etc. you at first write some data to location at `newValPtr` (1), then write value of `newValPtr ` in queue (2), another thread read stored pointer (3), and then read data by this pointer (4). for at (4) will be visible all data written at (1) - need do (2) with release and (3) with acquire

Comment: interesting - `InterlockedCompareExchange64(&tailIndex..)` is compiled ? if take to account that `tailIndex` is `long` and `InterlockedCompareExchange64` wait for `__int64*` ?

Comment: also you need first store `newValPtr`and then move `tailIndex` forward. so order must be next - (2) -(3)-(1)

Comment: For some reason, my IDE isn't complaining - I think its because I put everything into a .h file because I heard I was supposed to do that when using "template <typename T>". I'm pretty sure you're right and it won't compile though

Comment: Ok I think I understand the point about newValPtr - I must ensure that the data being written to the location specified by newValPtr is present before the location itself is made visible to other threads, which I am currently not doing. This has nothing to do with code reordering, which answers my original question. Thank you.

Your other point about moving forward the tailIndex last, though - there can be multiple producers running, so don't I need to reserve a spot in the messageQueue first, before putting a message inside?

Comment: if store via `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` only to 0 slot, you not need reserve it before. and can move `tailIndex` after this - first store, than move index, of course if consumer pop 0 value is ok - possible do and in your order. only anyway need (2) set on first place, and in check for queue full at (1) step, when you reserve index but not in (3). also in this case in (3) you not need compareexchange but only insterlocked store with release (because you unique allocated index)

Comment: That makes sense. I now understand why its possible to store newValPtr first and move the tailIndex last, but I still do not understand why its preferable to do it in that order. The Queue is actually a circular buffer, so I cannot check for overflow by just comparing tailIndex to MAXQUEUESIZE. By reserving slots, I can use array[reservedSlot]!=null to test if the buffer is full in 3), whereas if I store without reserving, I would need to use the array[tailIndex]!=null check in step 1) and would have to test for buffer overflow some other way. Thank you again for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Are line 68 and 90 supposed to be '%' instead of '&'?

I don't think the conditional on line 60 works correctly. _tail should never exceed size - 1, and because head is always positive, the only way 'tail>=head+size-1' returns true is if head == 0 and if tail == size-1, which isn't the only case where the queue is full, right?

Comment: At any rate though, I don't mean to make you code for me. You already answered the original question and explained what was wrong to me anyways, so that's all I can really ask for.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, if a function is structured such that the compiler can't reorder any of the code anyways because doing so would affect single-threaded behavior, is there a difference between any of the variants of an Interlocked function, or all they all effectively the same? Is the only difference between them how they interact with code reordering?

You may be confusing C++ *statements* with *instructions*. Your question isn't CPU specific, so you have to pretend you have no idea what the CPU instructions look like.

Consider this code:

```
if (a == 2)
{
    b = 5;
}
```

Now, here's an example of a re-ordering of this code that doesn't affect a single thread:

```
int c = b;
b = 5;
if (a != 2)
    b = c;
```

This performs the same operations but in a different order. It has no effect on single-threaded code. But, of course, if another thread was accessing `b`, it could see a value of `5` from this code even if `a` was never `2`.

**Thus it could also see a value of `5` from the original code even if `a` is never 2!**

Why, because the two bits of code perform the same from the point of view of a single thread. And unless you use operations with guaranteed threading semantics, that's all the compiler, CPU, caches, and other platform components need to preserve.

So most likely, your belief that reordering any of the code would affect single-threaded behavior is probably incorrect. There's lots of ways to reorder and optimize code that doesn't affect single-threaded behavior.

Comment: This goes by the name of "speculative execution" rather than "out of order execution", but it is a real thing for modern processors so the answer is quite correct apart from calling this transformation "reordering".

Comment: @BenVoigt It's kind of both, as the write to `b` (in the case where it is in fact set to `5`) occurs before the test of `a`.

Comment: "Speculative" implies that the action is taken (or at least prepared) before it is known whether it should be.  Now, real speculative execution implementations seem to hold the potential result in a shadow CPU register where it can be used to satisfy dataflow dependencies for further speculation, without letting it actually ever reach memory that another core might see (this is why side channel attacks like the fact that speculation has observable effects on cache are such a big deal).  But there's certainly nothing in the C++ sequential consistency memory model preventing visible speculation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an document on the msdn Explained the difference: [Acquire and Release Semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/acquire-and-release-semantics).

For the sample:

```
 a++;
 b++;
 c++;
```

- If we use acquire semantics to increment `a`, other processors would always see the increment of `a` before the increments of `b` and `c`;
- If we use release semantics to increment `c`, other processors would always see the increments of `a` and `b` before the increment of `c`;
- the `InterlockedXxx` routines perform, have both acquire and release semantics by default.

More specific, for 4 values:

```
 a++;
 b++;
 c++;
 d++;
```

- If we use acquire semantics to increment `b`, other processors would always see the increment of `b` before the increments of `c` and `d`;
  The order may be `a->b->c,d` or `b->a,c,d`.
- If we use release semantics to increment `c`, other processors would always see the increments of `a` and `b` before the increment of `c`;
  The order may be `a,b->c->d` or `a,b,d->c`.

To quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565699/10611792) of @antiduh:

> Acquire says "only worry about stuff after me". Release says "only
> worry about stuff before me". Combining those both is a full memory
> barrier.

Comment: Is that the only difference between the three forms of an Interlocked function? Is there a preferred version in situations where all three would result in correct behavior?

Comment: Nevermind - I received help from the other comment chains

Answer (score 0):

All three versions prevent the compiler from moving code across the function call, but the compiler is not the only place that reordering takes place.

Modern CPUs have "out-of-order execution" and even "speculative execution".  Acquire and release semantics cause the code to compiler to instructions with flags or prefixes controlling reordering within the CPU.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.
Still though, as far as I can tell, it doesn't look like my code is safe to reorder from a single threaded point of view. Shouldn't that prevent reordering of its statements anyways?

Comment: @ChristopherInokuchi - what reordered you think can be here ?

Comment: @ChristopherInokuchi: The CPU uses techniques like register renaming and reading from internal processor cache to make the current thread behave correctly even in the presence of reordering.  Something like `*p = f(); g(p);` can be turned into an actual execution order that cannot even be expressed in C.  The actual memory store to `*p` is likely to take place somewhere in the middle of function `g`, and any time `g` reads from `*p` prior to that write, instead of hitting memory it will actually be satisfied by the CPU internal *store buffer* which is waiting to be written out.